# Trouble Understanding how To Prove Basis of $P_1$

Tags: linear-algebra

So the Question I'm currently trying to do is:

> Let $E_1 = \{x, 1\}$ and $E_2 = \{2x − 1, 2x + 1\}$. Show that both $E_1$ and $E_2$ constitute (ordered)
> bases of the vector space $P_1$.

**Attempt So Far:** (not very sure I've been doing this correctly)

So $P_1$ here is represented by: $\{1,x\}$ since it's a polynomial basis of $1$.

And To prove a basis I need to show that: it spans and it is linearly independent.

For $E_1$: I state that since $E_1$ isn't a scalar multiple of $P_1$ (visually we can see that) it is linearly independent. Since it is linearly independent it implies that it spans. So it fulfills both making it a basis of $P_1$.

I just want to know if what I've done so far is correct and If I approach $E_2$ the same way as $E_1$? Since overall I'm a little confused on how proving basis works.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Since $E_1$ is a set with two polynomials and $P_1$ is the set of all polynomials whose degree is smaller than or equal to $1$, what does it *mean* to assert that $E_1$ isn't a scalar multiple of $P_1$? And why it would follow from linear independence that it spans the whole space?

Comment: To assert it isn't a scalar multiple of $P_1$ here means that 
$E_1$'s only solution to $c_1$$v_1$ + .... + $c_k$$v_k$ = 0 is $c_i$ = 0 for all i. If dim *V* = n, then any set of n linearly independent vector should span right?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is certainly right but I'm gonna flesh it out a bit with details.

As you said, $E_1:=\{1,x\}$ is linearly independent and a quick reason would be $x\neq a1\quad\forall a\in K$ since $x\notin K$. It is not exactly clear to me what you mean by "$E_1$ isn't a scalar multiple of $P_1$". Anyway since they are linearly independent, they span a 2 dimensional vector space.

It is clear that $E_1\subset P_1$, therefore $span(E_1)\subseteq P_1$ (since $span(E_1)$ and $P_1$ are both vector spaces). So if we already know that $P_1$ is 2 dimensional then we are done because $span(E_1)$ is a 2 dimensional subspace of $P_1$ and therefore the span is equal to $P_1$.

If we don't know the dimension of $P_1$, we still have to show that $P_1\subseteq spanE_1$. So we know that every element $p\in P_1$ can be written as $p=a_1+a_2x$ for $a_1,a_2\in K$ (Definition of $P_1$) but this is a linear combination of $1$ and $x$ therefore $p\in span(E_1)$. Now we are done.

For $E_2$ you can pretty much follow the same steps:

1. Show linear independence
2. If you know the dimension of $P_1$ you are done
3. Otherwise show that every element of $P_1$ can be written as a an element of $span(E_2)$.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late response was traveling for the past couple of days. Thank-you for the help this cleared up my misconceptions a great deal!